# Strongly typed collection for use both in COM and CLR

Tags: c#, collections, com, vbscript, interop

I'm trying to implement a typed collection that is intented for use both in .NET and COM (Windows Script Host) environment.

MSDN declares that one must to implement IEnumerable to make collection accessible to VB/VBS For Each statement:

```
[ComVisible]
[Guid]
interface IMyCollection : IEnumerable
{
    new IEnumerator GetEnumerator(); // required because of well-known COM interop inheritance issue
}
```

This works fine in VBScript/JScript, but for CLR/C# foreach statement this collection seems untyped.

Tried to make the collection interface strongly typed as follows. Now the collection works perfectly in C# but raises an error in VB because _NewEnum method (with id(-4)) is missing in TLB

```
[ComVisible]
[Guid]
interface IMyCollection : IEnumerable<IMyItem>
{

}
```

The following code works fine in VBScript but makes the collection untyped for .NET clients again:

```
[ComVisible]
[Guid]
interface IMyCollection : IEnumerable<IMyItem>
{
    new IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}
```

Also tried to implement _NewEnum manually by returning an object that implements the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IEnumVARIANT` but with no success. Method was exported to TLB by tlbexp utility but with no MIDL id attribute at all.

How could I solve this?

Comment: Can't understand the question, can you elaborate / add more details..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make IMyItem "ComVisible"? If it is not ComVisible, I guess IMyItem will be recognizede as VARIANT with untyped.